# obtener valor de un td mediante un onchange select en otro td dentro del mismo tr en un foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Tengo esta tabla creada con la paginación de `laravel 5.3` se utiliza un `foreach`

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

              <tbody>
                @foreach($usuarios as $key => $tag)
                  <tr id="caputracorreo" data-userid="{{$tag->email}}">
                    <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $tag->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $tag->email}}</td>


                    <td> <select class="form-control" id="estadoactualiza" name="estadoactualiza" data-userid="{{$tag->email}}" onchange="actualizar(this)">
                      @foreach($estados as $estado)
                        @if ($estado->id == $tag->id_estado)
                         <option selected value="{{$estado->id}}">{{$estado->nombre}}</option>
                        @else
                        <option value="{{$estado->id}}">{{$estado->nombre}}</option>
                         @endif
                      @endforeach
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>

            {{ $usuarios->links('vendor.pagination.paginadorusuarios') }}
```

y tengo este js con la acción del `onchange`

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
 function actualizar() {
 var id_estado = document.getElementById("estadoactualiza").value;
 var userid = $(caputracorreo).data('userid');
 alert (userid);
 }
</script>
```

Quiere obtener el `td` anterior del `select`, pero siempre me regresa el primer correo, digamos el primer `td` correo.

Comment: Veo que estás usando ID's para recuperar los datos. Evidentemente, esto te devolverá solamente los datos del primero ya que los ID's deberían ser **ÚNICOS** y pertenecer a un solo elemento. Deberías usar clases en vez de ID's.

Comment: Estás comentando que se ejecuta con un evento on change, pero sólo publicaste la parte de `$('document').ready()`

Comment: tampoco estan los ids #superbotton y #superenlace en el html

Comment: @Mariano una disculpa me equivoque al pasar el codigo ya esta el codigo correcto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Primero, un ID es irrepetible(o al menos así debería ser), por lo tanto debes hacer tus ids unicos para poder referenciarlos:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

              <tbody>
                $index = 0;
                @foreach($usuarios as $key => $tag)
                  <tr id="caputracorreo" data-userid="{{$tag->email}}">
                    <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $tag->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $tag->email}}</td>


                    <td> <select class="form-control" id="estadoactualiza{{ $index }}" name="estadoactualiza" data-userid="{{$tag->email}}" onchange="actualizar({{ $index }})">
                      @foreach($estados as $estado)
                        @if ($estado->id == $tag->id_estado)
                         <option selected value="{{$estado->id}}">{{$estado->nombre}}</option>
                        @else
                        <option value="{{$estado->id}}">{{$estado->nombre}}</option>
                         @endif
                      @endforeach
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>

            {{ $usuarios->links('vendor.pagination.paginadorusuarios') }}
```

y tengo este js con la acción del `onchange`

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
 function actualizar(numberid) {
 var id_estado = document.getElementById("estadoactualiza"+numberid).value;
 var userid = $(caputracorreo).data('userid');
 alert (userid);
 }
</script>
```

Se hace el id dinámico con un contador, ese id lo pasas como parámetro en tu función y la usas dentro de la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Al asignar el id del select que queres obtener debes hacer que tenga un nombre único, talvez asignandole el identificador de cada fila. Por ejemplo:

```
id="estadoactualiza_{{ $key }}"
```

Luego, en el evento onchange pasa el mismo identificador

```
onchange="actualizar({{ $key }})"
```

En tu función **actualizar()** ahora deberás de ir a buscar el elemento que acabas de hacer único:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  function actualizar(idunico) {
    var id_estado = document.getElementById("estadoactualiza_" + idunico).value;
    /* El resto de tu función va aquí... */
  }
</script>
```

Espero que te sirva.